# File monitoring to pre-empt hacker

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, security, monitoring

We have a hacker occasionally attempting to hack a site, and so far unsuccessful, but I would like a way to determine if the site has been compromised (i.e., files edited). The type of attacks are LFI and attempting to inject iFrames in some source files. What can I install on my Debian server to alert me via an e-mail if certain files or directories are modified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install Tripwire and introduce a set of dicrectory to Tripwire, When a file has been changed, Tripwire notifies sysadmin.

Comment: Thank you @MohsenPahlevanzadeh. I will ask my sys admin to install.

Comment: does TripWire require root access? According to my sysadmin they will not install software on the server that require root access?

Comment: for installation yes,

Comment: However i don't try to compile tell him/her to try compile it.